# Delphi - Reading from a log file that changes every second

Tags: delphi

I need to read from a .log file that is constantly changing by another application. (more data being added frequently)

So I have this to begin with:

```
var
    LogFile: TStrings;
    Stream: TStream;
   begin
   LogFile := TStringList.Create;
   try
      Stream := TFileStream.Create(Log, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
      try
         LogFile.LoadFromStream(Stream);
      finally
         Stream.Free;
      end;

      while LogFile.Count > Memo1.Lines.Count do
      Memo1.Lines.Add(LogFile[Memo1.Lines.Count]);
   finally
      LogFile.Free;
   end;
end;
```

This works perfectly fine. It updates the memo at real time with the data being added. However some of the data being added I don't want to see in the memo. I wish to not add these lines, but still have the memo updated at real time without the junk lines.

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd clearly need to check to see if the line has content you want to include, and only add it if it has that content (or not add it if you don't want to include it, whichever is the case). It would also be much more efficient to keep track of the last line in the `LogFile` you processed previously, so you could skip those lines each time - if you make the variable a private member of the form itself, it will automatically be initialized to 0 when your application starts:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    //... other stuff added by IDE
  private
    LastLine: Integer;
  end;


// At the point you need to add the logfile to the memo
for i := LastLine to LogFile.Count - 1 do
begin
  if ContentWanted(LogFile[i]) then
    Memo1.Lines.Append(LogFile[i]);
  Inc(LastLine);
end;
```

So to handle this completely based on your code:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    //... IDE stuff here
  private
    FLastLogLine: Integer;
    procedure ProcessLogFile;
  public
    // Other stuff
  end;

procedure TForm1.ProcessLogFile;
var
  Log: TStringList;
  LogStream: TFileStream;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Log := TStringList.Create;
  try
    LogStream := TFileStream.Create(...);
    try
      Log.LoadFromStream(LogStream);
    finally
      LogStream.Free;
    end;

    for i := FLastLogLine to Log.Count - 1 do
      if Pos('[Globals] []', Log[i]) <>0 then
        Memo1.Lines.Append(Log[i]);

    // We've now processed all the lines in Log. Save
    // the last line we processed as the starting point
    // for the next pass.
    FLastLogLine := Log.Count - 1;      
  finally
    Log.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := False;
  try
    ProcessLogFile;
  finally
    Timer1.Enabled := True;
  end;
end;
end;
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what i was looking for :)

Comment: If the log file gets large you'd want to read in only the new content.

Comment: The log file does eventually become large, however won't i need to load the entire file regardless each time i run my application?

Comment: @David: Agreed. At that point, you could use a stream, and save the last byte position instead of tracking the line position, seek to that position, and read from there to the end of the stream. I have a text stream implementation from Primoz that works really well for that sort of thing.

Comment: A better option is to simply not close the file. Open the stream, read to EOF, wait for the file to grow again and then simply read from the current stream position to the new EOF, and repeat as needed. I wrote a log viewer app that uses a technique similar to this (but more advanced as it uses a sliding memory map for the actual reading, and a virtual ListView for the display. It displays millions of log lines but keeps memory usage down to just a few MB at a time).

Comment: @Remy: That's true. As I said in the comment to David, if the file were large, I'd replace the above with a stream and just read from `Position` to `Size` without closing the file. It becomes slightly complex, though, if you have to parse for CR/LF in order to add full lines of text; simply appending to the memo's Text can get pretty slow unless you're willing to work at it.

Comment: That's when buffering techniques start coming into play. Read the file data into a buffer, then parse out full lines from the buffer and leave a partial line in the buffer so it can be finished by later reads. As for appending to a Memo, using the `SelText` property is faster and more efficient than using the `Text`property or the `Lines.Append()` method.

Answer (score 1):

I know its been a couple of weeks since i last posted here, but i rewrote the entire application and came up with this piece of code, which is working perfectly!

Basically i do not call .free on the stream or stringlist and am able to set the initial stream size then check if its changed, hence getting the data i need and not the entire file!

Thanks everyone for helping!

```
procedure TForm1.GetEndLogFile;
begin
  LogFile := TStringList.Create;
  Stream := TFileStream.Create('C:\Users\John\Documents\chat.log', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
  LogFile.LoadFromStream(Stream);
  i := Stream.Size;
end;

procedure TForm1.LogFileRefresh;
var
  buf: string;
begin
  if i <> Stream.Size then
  begin
    SetLength(buf, Stream.Size);
    Stream.Seek(i, Stream.Size);
    Stream.Read(buf[1], Stream.Size);
    i := Stream.Size;
    Memo1.Lines.Append(Buf);
    //ShowMessage(buf);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Since you call `Stream.Read(buf[1], Stream.Size)` you are still reading the whole file, every time. Consequently you append the whole content to the memo, every time. Are you sure that this is working perfectly?

Comment: It's working as intended. The entire file does not append to the memo, only the lines that are added after i have loaded the file. It's wierd because `Stream.Read(buf[1], Stream.Size);` always only ever shows lines added after i have the file opened. I just realised that it works without `Stream.Seek(i, Stream.Size);` which has confused me more!

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure TForm1.GetEndLogFile;
var
  LogFile: TStrings;
  Stream: TStream;
begin
  LogFile := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Stream := TFileStream.Create(LogFile, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
    try
      LogFile.LoadFromStream(Stream);
      EndOfFile := LogFile.Count;
    finally
      Stream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    LogFile.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.LogFileRefresh;
var
  LogFile2: TStrings;
  Stream2: TStream;
  i: Integer;
begin
  LogFile2 := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Stream2 := TFileStream.Create(LogFile, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
    try
      LogFile2.LoadFromStream(Stream2);
    finally
      Stream2.Free;
    end;
    for i := EndOfFile to LogFile2.Count -1 do
    begin
      if Pos('[Globals] []',LogFile2[i])<>0 then
      Memo1.Lines.Append(LogFile2[i]);
      Inc(EndOfFile);
    end;
  finally
    LogFile2.Free
  end;
end;
```

Basically came up with this, and its working perfectly fine. Should i run into any problems this way? Is there a neater way to do this?

Comment: Yes. You're loading the log file twice every time (once in GetEndLogFile and once in LogFileRefresh). Don't. :-) I'll edit my answer to provide more details for you.

Comment: kinda messed this up!